# ThreeJS Camera Frustrum frustum.containsPoint is always returning true

Tags: canvas, three.js

I am trying to get all the objects that the camera can see because I want to update the position of the objects it can't see.

frustum.containsPoint always returns true which is the biggest issue

any help is much appreciated

```js
camera.updateMatrix();
  camera.updateMatrixWorld();

  var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
  var projScreenMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  projScreenMatrix.multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse);

  // frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(camera.projectionMatrix);
  frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse));

  for (let index = 0; index < scene.children.length; index++) {
    scene.children[index].updateMatrix(); // make sure plane's local matrix is updated
    scene.children[index].updateMatrixWorld();

    if (frustum.containsPoint(scene.children[index])) {
      //stuff happens...
      if (scene.children[index].name === "coin") {
        scene.children[index].rotation.x += 0.01;
        scene.children[index].position.y -= 0.1;
      }
      // console.log("mesh in view Frustrum");
    } else {
      console.log("mesh not in view Frustrum");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
frustum.containsPoint(scene.children[index])
```

it should be:

```
frustum.intersectsObject(scene.children[index])
```

`Scene.children` does not hold points but 3D objects.